# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number - oci_bind_by_name

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

```
$letter= "A";
$statement = oci_parse($connection, "select * from person where firstname like ':letter%'");
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':letter', $letter);
```

I've already tested it with "select * from person" and it worked.
I want to get a list of persons which first names start with "A". Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your query to this:

```
oci_parse($connection, "select * from person where firstname like :letter || '%'");
```